# How do you wire a multi-gang switch?

Tags: electrical

Some of my lights are flickering and I can't figure out why. One thought is that I wired stuff incorrectly. Right now, all the live wires are tied together (no loops or anything) and the same for the neutrals. Should I add looping or additional wires?

In other words, I have 3 Insteon switches and 1 live wire connected together. Then I have 3 light fixture and 3 insteon switch neutral wires connected together. Is it ok to connect them all together (assuming I have a large enough wire connector), or do I need to have additional wires and stuff?

[image]

Comment: Are all the switches in one box? Can you post a picture of the wiring in the box(es)?

Comment: Yes. I added a diagram of what the wires look like

Comment: Two questions arising from the drawing: Where is the main neutral line? And, on the left hand side, are the maroon wires connecting to the red wire from the switch?

Answer (score 1):

Your wiring diagram appears to be correct, assuming that only one switch controls each light.

All neutral wires (white) should be joined together. However, it is possible to have a poor connection when trying to twist four wires together for a wirenut. You might try one of the [push-in connectors](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-34-Yellow-In-Sure-4-Port-Connector-100-Pack-30-1034P/202894312) that grabs each wire separately.

[image: pushin]

Similarly, all hot leads can be connected. In the case of Insteon, the black wire is hot. The red is load and each of them needs to be seprately connected to the hot lead to the fixture it controls.

The following is the diagram [Insteon](http://cache.insteon.com/documentation/2477D-en.pdf) provides

[image: insteon diagram]

Double check your connections and consider different connectors.

Finally, check your bulbs to make sure they are compatible with Insteon, especially if you are using dimmer switches. Some bulbs do not dim or need special types of dimmers.